# ASIHTTPRequest: (iOS) Properly Download & Stream Data to Disk

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

Does anyone have an outline for the proper way to setup ASIHTTPRequest to stream a download to disk, instead of downloading it all in memory then writing to disk?

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to write it to disk as it receives the data.

```
ASIHTTPRequest * request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:absolutePath];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];
```

Do I need to implement any delegate methods so that it does indeed write to disk?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

from ASIHTTPRequest docs:

> When downloading data to a file using downloadDestinationPath, data
> will be saved in a temporary file while the request is in progress.
> This file’s path is stored in temporaryFileDownloadPath. When the
> request completes successfully, one of two things happen:
>
> If the data is gzip compressed (see information on gzip compression), the compressed file will be uncompressed into
> downloadDestinationPath, and the temporary file will be deleted
>
> If the data is not compressed, the temporary file is moved to downloadDestinationPath, overwriting any previous file

So, yes: it should be written to file as it downloads, but not to the final destination until the download is complete.